# API для Internet Explorer

Tags: api, internet-explorer, png

Ребята хелп! Мне нужно каким-то образом в Internet Explorer получить вызов окна Save picture as... А потом из списка выбрать формат *.png и сохраниться. Уже неделю бьюсь над задачей. Результата нет. Пишу на Python. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Почему нужно именно через Internet Explorer?

Comment: У меня SVG иконки. нужно перегнать в PNG. Inkscape, Image Magic и другие не всегда корректно делают это, так как структура моих SVG разная. А с IE вопросов нет. Поэтому хочу юзать его. Но иконок много, руками задолбаюсь. Другие браузеры не подходят, так как не могут сохранить как PNG.